# Return view() not working in my function. How to solve it?

Tags: php, laravel

This function is not working. What wrong is going on here?? Attached the controller and route. Instead of going to cancel page it is redirecting to login page. Any help guys?

This is the controller file where the function goes:

```
public function payment_cancel(Request $request){
        if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
            $merchantTxnNo = $_POST['MerchantTxnNo'];
            $TxnResponse = $_POST['TxnResponse'];
            $txnAmount= $_POST['TxnAmount'];
            $OrderNo = $_POST['OrderNo'];
            $fosterid = $_POST['fosterid'];
            $hashkey = $_POST['hashkey'];
            return view('admin.billing.cancel', [
                'merchantTxnNo' => $merchantTxnNo,
                'TxnResponse' => $TxnResponse,
                'txnAmount' => $txnAmount,
                'OrderNo' => $OrderNo,
                'fosterid' => $fosterid,
                'hashkey' => $hashkey,
            ]);
        }
    }
```

This the route file for the blade file

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['account-setup']], function () {
                Route::post('billing/unsubscribe',  'AdminBillingController@cancelSubscription')->name('billing.unsubscribe');
                Route::post('billing/razorpay-payment',  'AdminBillingController@razorpayPayment')->name('billing.razorpay-payment');
                Route::post('billing/razorpay-subscription',  'AdminBillingController@razorpaySubscription')->name('billing.razorpay-subscription');
                Route::get('billing/data',  'AdminBillingController@data')->name('billing.data');
                Route::get('billing/select-package/{packageID}',  'AdminBillingController@selectPackage')->name('billing.select-package');
                Route::get('billing', 'AdminBillingController@index')->name('billing');
                Route::get('billing/packages', 'AdminBillingController@packages')->name('billing.packages');
                Route::post('billing/online-payment', 'AdminBillingController@online_payments')->name('payments.online');
                Route::post('billing/cancel', 'AdminBillingController@payment_cancel')->name('payments.cancel');
                Route::post('billing/payment-stripe', 'AdminBillingController@payment')->name('payments.stripe');
                Route::post('billing/payment-authorize', 'AuthorizeController@createSubscription')->name('payments.authorize');
                Route::post('billing/check-authorize-subscription', 'AuthorizeController@checkSubscription')->name('check-authorize-subscription');
                Route::get('billing/invoice-download/{invoice}', 'AdminBillingController@download')->name('stripe.invoice-download');
                Route::get('billing/razorpay-invoice-download/{id}', 'AdminBillingController@razorpayInvoiceDownload')->name('billing.razorpay-invoice-download');
                Route::get('billing/offline-invoice-download/{id}', 'AdminBillingController@offlineInvoiceDownload')->name('billing.offline-invoice-download');
                Route::get('billing/paystack-invoice-download/{id}', 'AdminBillingController@paystackInvoiceDownload')->name('billing.paystack-invoice-download');
                Route::get('billing/mollie-invoice-download/{id}', 'AdminBillingController@mollieInvoiceDownload')->name('billing.mollie-invoice-download');
                Route::get('billing/authorize-invoice-download/{id}', 'AdminBillingController@authorizeInvoiceDownload')->name('billing.authorize-invoice-download');
```

Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use App\InvoiceSetting;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;

class AccountSetup
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $company = auth()->user()->company;
        $invoiceSetting = InvoiceSetting::first();
        
        if (!$company->company_name || !$company->company_email ||  !$company->address || !$invoiceSetting->invoice_prefix || !$invoiceSetting->estimate_prefix || !$invoiceSetting->credit_note_prefix || !$invoiceSetting->template || is_null($invoiceSetting->due_after) || !$invoiceSetting->invoice_terms){
            return Redirect::route('admin.account-setup.index');
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would guess that either a) your `account-setup` middleware is redirecting the user when they are not logged in or b) one of the parent routes/groups of the `Route::group` shown is doing similar (probably using the `auth` middleware). Are you logged in when you visit this path and get redirected? If it's not a auth based redirect issue then you should post the code for your `account-setup` middleware too.

Comment: You use `POST` method in route So not show view. check session path and config values

Comment: i have added the middleware @qooplmao

Comment: i didnt get you @MohammadrezaGolshahi can you please explain if you dont mind?

Comment: I'm going to guess that it is redirecting to `admin.account-setup.index` which is requiring you to be logged in (possibly on a different firewall). Upload the output of the command `./artisan route:list --columns=Method,URI,Name,Middleware --name={name}` with `{name}` being the name of each of the routes `payments.cancel` and `admin.account-setup.index` (you will need to run the command once per route).